# Prove that $\tau \rho = \rho^ {−1}\tau.$

Tags: group-theory

Consider $\rho = (1; 2; 3; 4)$ and $\tau = (2; 3)(1; 4)$ in $S_4$.
Prove that $\tau \rho = \rho^ {−1}\tau .$

I know this is relatively simple but my answer isn't matching so I am doing something wrong. Just want to make sure that $\rho^{-1}= (4;1;2;3)$. If so I must doing my composition wrong. Can someone show me the correct way.

Comment: What does this notation with the semicolons mean?  Is $\rho$ a cycle or is it the identity $1 \mapsto 1, 2 \mapsto 2$ etc.?

Comment: Its just the cycle notation that my professor showed us. Just following it. $\rho$ is a cycle. I see what you are saying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$
\rho(1) = 2, \rho(2) = 3, \rho(3) = 4, \rho(4) = 1,
$$
which implies that
$$
\rho^{-1}(2) = 1, \rho^{-1}(3) = 2, \rho^{-1}(4) = 3, \rho^{-1} (1) = 4,
$$
or,
$$
\rho^{-1}(1) = 4, \rho^{-1}(2) = 1, \rho^{-1}(3) = 2, \rho^{-1} (4) = 3.
$$
Thus
$$
\rho^{-1} = ( 1; 4; 3; 2 ).
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes yes it definitely does. I forgot that last step. Thanks :)