# How do we prove that $\tau \rho = \rho^{-1} \tau$ in general for $D_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I found a problem similar to this one here: [Prove that $\tau \rho = \rho^ {−1}\tau.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652734/prove-that-tau-rho-rho-%e2%88%921-tau) except this is a particular example. I would think the best route to proving this is by a homomorphism from $\phi:D_{2n} \mapsto S_{n}$. But I have no idea how to translate $\tau,\rho$ as cycles. Any hints or tips would be appreciated. If this question has an answer somewhere else let me know.

Comment: How do you define $D_{2n}$? Geometrically?

Comment: What is $D_{2n}$? Yes, I know what it is, but in order to answer your question, it is necessary to know how you define it. E.g. the definition via generators and relations already includes the answer.

Comment: What, to you, are $\tau$ and $\rho$? A reflection and a rotation, respectively?

Comment: That's the problem. With my algebra class, the professor defined $D_{2n}$ as the set of all rotations ($\rho$) and symmetries ($\tau$).  Although in another problem he does state $D_{2n}$ is generated by $<\tau, \rho: \tau^{2} = id, \rho^{n} = id, \tau\rho = \rho^{-1}\tau>$ but like I said the class has been confusing.

Comment: Your idea is good in that case. Enumerate the vertices of the polygon and assign a permutation to $\tau$ and $\rho$. This gives you a monomorphism and you can simply do the calculation by permutations.

Comment: Your writing is confused (probably because of how it was presented). $\rho$ is a *single* rotation; the set of all rotations would consists of $1,\rho,\rho^2,\ldots$. And $\tau$ is a *single* reflection; the set of all reflections would require a bunch of symbols, or specifying one rotation and then composing with the rotations to cover all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the vertices of a regular $n$-gon by the first $n$ nonzero natural numbers. Then the symmetries of the $n$-gon correspond to particular elements of $S_n$. If any two of these permutations are the same, then clearly they are defined by the same symmetry; so the correspondence is injective. Fix a reflection $\tau$ and a rotation $\rho$. Use the fact that for any $\alpha,\beta\in S_n$, with $\alpha=(a_{i_1}\dots a_{i_{l_1}})\dots (a_{i_k}\dots a_{i_{l_k}})$ the cycle decomposition of $\alpha$, we have

$$\beta\alpha \beta^{-1}=(\beta(a_{i_1})\dots\beta (a_{i_{l_1}}))\dots (\beta(a_{i_k})\dots\beta( a_{i_{l_k}})).$$

Then note that $\rho $ corresponds to an $n$-cycle whose inverse is $(r_n\dots r_1)$, where $\rho=(r_1\dots r_n)$.

Comment: You need to make sure that the correspondence is injective!

Comment: Thank you, @MariusS.L. Good catch! I have edited my answer accordingly.